# How do i create stacked bar chart using ChartJs in Filament?

Tags: php, laravel, chart.js, laravel-filament

Good day, I need your assistance/guidance in creating a stacked bar chart using Chartjs in Laravel Filament. I have a tabled named 'Tasks' that has a relation with 'Clients' table. The fields for each table are as follows

**Tasks**

- ID
- title
- notes
- priority
- status
- type
- owner_id
- client_id
- created_at
- updated_at

**Clients**

- id
- client_name
- city

I want to create a stacked bar chart that will show all tasks per client grouped by their priority. I the following code snippets

1. Getting all Tasks Per Client and Grouping By client_name and priority

```
$data = Tasks::select('clients.client_name as client_name', 'tasks.priority', DB::raw('COUNT(tasks.id) as task_count'))
           ->join('clients', 'tasks.client_id', '=', 'clients.id')
           ->groupBy('clients.client_name', 'tasks.priority')
           ->orderBy('clients.client_name')
           ->orderBy('tasks.priority')
           ->get();
```

2. Preparing The Labels For Chart

```
// Prepare labels array
$labels = array_keys(reset($data));
```

3. Preparing the datasets

```
 // Prepare datasets array
        $datasets = [];
        foreach ($data as $client => $priorities) {
            $dataset = [
                'label' => $client,
                'backgroundColor' => [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.8)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.8)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.8)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.8)'
                ],
                'data' => array_values($priorities),
            ];
            $datasets[] = $dataset;
        }
```

4. Returning the Chart in Filament

```
 return [
            'datasets' => $datasets,
            'labels' => $labels
        ];
```

5. The whole code

```
<?php

namespace App\Filament\Widgets;

use App\Models\Tasks;
use Filament\Widgets\ChartWidget;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class TasksByPriority extends ChartWidget
{
    protected static ?string $heading = 'Tasks By Priority';

    public function getDescription(): ?string
    {
        return 'Summary of tasks created by priority';
    }

    protected static ?string $maxHeight = '300px';
    protected static ?string $pollingInterval = null;

    protected function getData(): array
    {
        $data = Tasks::select('clients.client_name as client_name', 'tasks.priority', DB::raw('COUNT(tasks.id) as task_count'))
            ->join('clients', 'tasks.client_id', '=', 'clients.id')
            ->groupBy('clients.client_name', 'tasks.priority')
            ->orderBy('clients.client_name')
            ->orderBy('tasks.priority')
            ->get();

        // Prepare labels array
        $labels = array_keys(reset($data));

        // Prepare datasets array
        $datasets = [];
        foreach ($data as $client => $priorities) {
            $dataset = [
                'label' => $client,
                'backgroundColor' => [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.8)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.8)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.8)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.8)'
                ],
                'data' => array_values($priorities),
            ];
            $datasets[] = $dataset;
        }

        return [
            'datasets' => $datasets,
            'labels' => $labels
        ];
    }

    protected function getType(): string
    {
        return 'bar';
    }
}
```

I get the following error
[image]

I want the end result to be as follows
[image]

This is how it looks like
[image]

Comment: It would appear that `$priorities` is not an array. Take a look at it with the debugger to see what you are actually processing there

Comment: @RiggsFolly, after converting priorities to an array, the chart shows in a manner i do not expect

Comment: How is the chart showing up and how would you like it to show up?

Comment: @LajosArpad i have updated the post above. please check the last part

Comment: So what does it look like now?

Comment: Hey @RiggsFolly, i have updated once again, please check